# A question about a function mathematical notation

Tags: notation

I am writing an engineering paper, which is supposed to be submitted to IEEE and wondering about the correct mathematical notation for one of the equations. Suppose there is a function which consists of three other functions
$$
y(t) = \begin{bmatrix} a(t)\\ b(t,x)\\ c(t) \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here only $b$ is a function of the variable $x$ and I want to emphasize on this in another equation. Can I write the followings?
$$
y(x) = b(x)
$$
This feels like $a$ and $c$ are thrown away. Is there a better way to represent the property?

Comment: Writing $y(x)=b(x)$ seems extremely confusing.   $b$ is a function of two variables, if nothing else. Perhaps you intend $b(x)$ to mean $b(x,x)$ but that's hardly obvious.   And for what purpose?  You have already defined $y(t)$, so $y(x)$ is known.  Though, wouldn't it make more sense to have defined $y(t,x)$ since $y$ is also a function of two variables?  Then, if you like, you could define $y(x)=y(x,x)$.

Comment: That is actually the problem. $y(t)$ is a measurement function of a dynamics model and in the general notation it should be explicitly defined as $y(t)$. Here $x$ (it is not the state) is an insignificant variable. Also $y$ is implicitly a function of $x$. Therefore, I can not write $y(t,x)$ where I initially define $y$. Only in a small subsection, I elaborate on the variable $x$ and its role.

Comment: Not following.  $y$ is an explicit function of $x$ since it is an explicit function of $b(t,x)$ which is an explicit function of $x$.   And you say $x$ is an "insignificant variable" and yet  the whole point is to define $y(x)$.

Comment: The point of mathematical notation is to clarify something efficiently.  What you are doing is anything but clarifying.

Comment: True that. $y$ is an explicit function of $x$. But $x$ itself and its role comes much later in the paper than the initial definition of $y$. First I have to elaborate on the system itself without mentioning $x$. Later, in order to prove a system property, I start talking about the variable $x$. Here I would like to introduce $x$ and its relevance to the system and its measurement function $y$. Also, I need to linearize $y$ according to $x$. The question is how I can emphasize that we have to linearize only $b(t,x)$ function to get the lineazed $y(t,x)$.

Comment: To state the obvious:  any notation that requires several paragraphs to explain is a poor notation. I have no idea what your functions are.  You introduced $x$ into the definition explicitly by writing $b(t,x)$.  Perhaps you dislike the variable $x$ and wish to hide it, but it is still there. And, again, the whole point of your question is to define $y(x)$ so I simply don't understand your insistence that $x$ is irrelevant.,

Comment: Aside from the confusion regarding $x$, why are you ignoring $a(t), c(t)$?  You define $y=y(t,x)$ as a triple of three functions.  Why ignore two of the three functions?  If you are only interested in $b(t,x)$ then just work with that.

Comment: Perhaps you just want to say that $$y = \begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{bmatrix}$$and mention only that $a,b,$ and $c$ depend on time, then later generalize your model to account for a dependence on $x$, and at that time explain that $a$ and $c$ are independent of $x$?

Comment: Alright. I will do it as you suggested. Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to say in words what you are trying to get the symbols to say.  $y$ should be $y(x,t)$ because it depends on both of them.  Then you can give a plan saying that you will deal with $t$ first and with $x$ later.

Comment: @RossMillikan Afaik referring to next sections is not a good practice.

Comment: It is not as justification for something you are doing.  It is fine if you are indicating the plan for your paper.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see your point. Thank you.